# How to Initialize OpaquePointer in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to use OpaquePointer in Swift.
This is my Code.

```
@State var OP : OpaquePointer = OpaquePointer.init(bitPattern: <#T##Int#>)
```

In my Project, I use SwiftGit2 Library.
And because of that, I must initialize the OpaquePointer.

It doesn't matter what way.

In addition, I put any bitPatter in the Parameter.
And, here is the Error

```
@State var OP : OpaquePointer = OpaquePointer.init(bitPattern: 1)
```

> Value of optional type 'OpaquePointer?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'OpaquePointer'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the compile error is telling you is that the initialiser that takes a bit pattern returns an optional `OpaquePointer`.

So you either should use it as an optional:

```
@State var OP: OpaquePointer? = OpaquePointer(bitPattern: 1)
```

Or if you're a 100% certain the opaque pointer is **never** nil, you can force unwrap it:

```
@State var OP: OpaquePointer = OpaquePointer(bitPattern: 1)!
```

However, if the `OpaquePointer` fails to initialise, your app will crash.

Please note that a bitPattern of 1 **will most certainly fail**, since this should point to an address in memory.

A better way to get an OpaquePointer is to derive it from an `UnsafePointer` or `UnsafeMutablePointer`, so you're sure the pointer is actually pointing to the thing you want it to.

What are you trying to point to? And do you really need an `OpaquePointer`? If so, I'd highly advise to not mess with pointers inside your SwiftUI view, do this stuff in a (or multiple) layers 'above' that (so either ViewModel or Model/Data).